# How to log more detail of 400 responses in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python, django, logging, django-rest-framework, http-status-code-400

I've got an endpoint built with Django Rest Framework, to which someone is posting data. Since this morning he's getting a lot of 400 responses. In my Kibana logging I can only confirm that he indeed receives a lot of 400 responses. I need to debug this, but I don't have a lot of info. So I want to log more detail about the 400 responses. So I thought of doing the following in my viewset

```
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        response = super().create(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return response
    except exceptions.ValidationError as e:
        logger.error(f"{e} in message: {request.data}")
        return Response(e, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

This seems to work, but it doesn't really feel like the most logical way of doing it. Is there a more pythonic way of logging 400 responses?

Comment: I would ask *him* for the payload he sent to the end-point.

Comment: I would love to, but he isn't the easiest to work with. So I really need to find this out on my end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check the **`response.status`** value, which will be an integer and then I log **`response.data`** which will be a `dict` like object.

Also, Logstash is very fond of JSON like items, this may more suitable in your case.

```
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    response = super().create(request, *args, **kwargs)
    if response.status == 400:
        logger.error(response.data)
        
    return response
```